# How to find the minimum data point that predicts the target class in longitudinal data

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, time-series, feature-selection

I am working on medical data where a screening is done regularly for 200 days. I need to know the minimum number of screenings that can predict the outcome. I also need to know the best time/times to do the screening. how can I approach this problem? I am using Python and my data is stored in an Excel sheet. I am planning to use a linear model and solve a classification problem.